# Regex Match Count and Scan

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, matcher

Is there a way that I could print the contents of each regex match within a loop? Say I have the following pattern:

```
1xxxx2xxxx3
```

If I have a matcher that is (?mi)(\d)...How could I iterate through the matches and print out the contents of each match?

```
ex) System.debug(match1) //should be 1
    System.debug(match2) //should be 2
    System.debug(match3) //should be 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your regex is correct you can do the following to iterate over the matches:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(yourRegex);
Matcher pm = p.matcher(yourString);
if (pm.matches()) {
    for (Integer i = 1; i <= pm.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.debug(pm.group(i));
    }
}
```

Reference: [Matcher Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm)

Comment: Thank you. Is there an advantage of using matches() in this scenario as opposed to find()?

Comment: Also I thought that groupCount() returned the number of groups in the formula, not the number of matches. I tried a similar loop using groupCount() and it didn't get me very far